# Script to write Excel data to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, excel, ssis

I need some sort of starting point for the following task:

Some kind of script should watch a certain folder for incoming excel files. These excel files all have a worksheet with an equal name. The script should then take a certain range of columns of each excel file run down all the rows and write the column data to a running Microsoft SQL Server table.

Now I don't know what scripting language I should/could use for this task. Maybe perl or windows power shell?

Hope you can point me to the right direction.

**UPDATE:** shouldn't I also look into SSIS since this seems to offer quite a lot of features?

Thank you.

Comment: "worksheet with an equal name" meaning it will always be the same name?

Comment: Is there a specific need to for it to be in a scripting language?  Powershell and Perl both require installing a package of some sort.  Why not built a service app?

Comment: perl for example is already installed and in use for other database tasks. And yes the the name will always be the same, it's a "helper"-worksheet so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Windows Service that can monitor a certain folder for a certain interval (say 10 minutes) using .Net.

Using ADO.Net, you can connect to both Excel workbooks and SQL sever perform SQL style data transformations.  If the Excel doc isn't conducive to performing SQL queries, there's alway MS Office interop to interface with Excel to select specific values of cells (this tends to be more difficult than the former).

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not the best way to do it... he did ask for a starting point.

Comment: It would using either option.  If using ADO.Net, you would use a connection string that refelcts the version using either ODBC or OleDB.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write a script in Perl or Python trying to call the file in the folder, and if successful, parse the data into either dictionaries/hashes (would be really easy to break rows and columns into a hash), or arrays, making it easy to write to a database.

Then (my knowledge is better in Python, sorry) use the PyODBC module, or whatever other module is necessary to connect to the server, and start writing. I am sorry if this is not as helpful, I am a beginner.